# Approaches i can follow to move 140,000 files/folders from one site to another inside the same tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have a SharePoint library named Marketing, which contain 137,000 files/folders + 769 GB.. as follow:-

[image]

now the library contains many subfolders with those storage matrix:-

[image: thumbnail image 2 of blog post titled]

and the Creative subfolder contain those storage matrix as well:-

[image]

now can i benefit from power automate or other built-in tools to move those files from one site to another within the same tenant? or this will not work? now i can not use the built-in move action in SharePoint due to its limitation:-

***Copying/Moving multiple files in a single operation has three requirements:
No more than 100-GB total file size.
No more than 30,000 files.
File size limits:
2 GB limit for OneNote files.
15 GB file size limit for cross-geo copy or move.***

any advice? on the best way to move the file/folders within the Marketing library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Migration software**

For large migrations of data between sites, you could utilise SharePoint migration software such as ShareGate.

**Use the copy to/move to functionality in SharePoint Online**

You could split the job in to multiple operations using the copy to or move to functionality in SharePoint Online.